Transform an AWS API Gateway Integration Response into a 204 No Content response
I have a working AWS API Gateway Method Integration that returns a payload, I'd prefer it to return no payload at all as an HTTP 204 No Content response.
The CloudFormation definition of a working version of the method. It just delegates to SQS to send a message.
# The rest of the Cloudformation template is boiler-plate API Gateway and elided.

  RestPost:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref RestResource
      AuthorizationType: NONE  # This method is public.
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        Type: AWS
        Credentials: !GetAtt Role.Arn
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sqs:path/${AWS::AccountId}/${Queue.QueueName}
        PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200  # This, the first one, is also the default match, so the code here means nothing
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: |
                {}  ## a minimal JSON document
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200  # This, the first one, is also the default match, so the code here means nothing

Enabling X-Ray has indeed shown that there is a fault in the method, but I cannot seem to extract any other useful information from it.
Change the ResponseTemplate to
#set($context.responseOverride.status = 202)
{}  ## a minimal JSON document

This works and correctly maps the status code from 200 OK to 202 Accepted.
Change the ResponseTemplate to
#set($context.responseOverride.status = 204)
{}  ## a minimal JSON document

This returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

So, while reducing my examples to the minimal possible to post the question I actually stumbled on the answer.
{} is still content, one must use null with a 204 response.
Irritatingly, one cannot return nothing, that is an error too.
E.g.
#set($context.responseOverride.status = 204)
null  ## turns out this is a minimal, valid JSON document

Where this gets a little confusing for me is due to two things:

Testing locally with localstack is very permissive (its behaviour is not consistent with AWS-proper), there's nothing in it's logs to help as it thinks it's OK
I'm still unsure how to find this error in AWS-proper.

